# setAdapter(adapter);?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Hello everyone I am Setting up a ViewPager but I keep getting an error with Set Adapter. this code links to a PagerAdapter.Can anyone help?

```
package com.test.viewpager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class  PagerAdapter extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();    
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);    
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);    
        myPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    }
}
```

here is the mypageradapter that i need to run

```
 package com.test.viewpager;


  import android.content.Context;
  import android.os.Parcelable;
  import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;


   class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter { 

public int getCount() {        
    return 5;      
    }     
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {     
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()        
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);       
    int resId = 0;       
    switch (position) {        
    case 0:                resId = R.layout.page1;         
    break;         
    case 1:                resId = R.layout.page2;           
    break;       
    case 2:                resId = R.layout.page3;     
    break;        
    case 3:                resId = R.layout.page4;          
    break;       
    case 4:                resId = R.layout.page5;   
    break;            }      
    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);    
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);        
    return view;        }   
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {      
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);        }    
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {         
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);        }        
public Parcelable saveState() {        
    return null;        }}
```

here is  the main xml that im using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"   
     android:layout_height="match_parent"   
      android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your `MyPagerAdapter` code please.

Comment: The logcat also, please.

Comment: what error have you got?

Comment: @onemach i get an error on the viewpager under the  "setAdapter"

Answer (score 1):

You named your activity class `PagerAdapter`, which is also the name of `android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter`.

Name it other way, and you will find the real bug, that you forgot to `import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;` in MyPagerAdapter.java

Answer (score -2):

It would also help if you posted some information about the error you're getting, such as a LogCat or stack trace or even error message.

Even though some mistakes stand out, it would be wrong of *us* to guess at your problem without having all the info. You could be running into a problem that has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: use "add comment" to add comments/notes to the question